# CyanogenMod tag removal

Tags: discussion

I'd like to suggest removal of [the CyanogenMod tag](https://askubuntu.com/tags/cyanogenmod/info).

I don't see how that tag has any relation to Ubuntu.

**EDIT:**

So the question now becomes... how do we go about removing it?

Comment: Keep in mind that Ubuntu Touch is based on the work of CyanogenMod.

Comment: @NathanOsman - So you're saying UT is essentially a heavily-modified build of Android?

Comment: @NathanOsman Out of the 3 tagged questions one contains an error message about CyanogenMod caused by phablet-dev-bootstrap (about a proprietary app that seems to have gotten obsolete over time on CyanogenMod) and the tag provides no value in that context. The other two are about users using CyanogenMod instead of Android, they are just poorly tagged and over-specific for AU. Questions that touch low level specifics about CyanogenMod can and have been tagged with `porting-ubuntu-touch`.

Comment: @NathanOsman CyanogenMod tag relates to CyanogenMod, not Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: I've deleted the tag from the two posts it was on. It should be gone tomorrow unless someone adds it back or to a new post.

Comment: Only as far as the drivers go, they initially used parts for a kickstart on compatibility, 'android' based phones still would have the same boot process and hardware, so they can reuse the system drivers for the diffrent chips, graphics, wifi etc. Basically nothing left to call android or cyanogen for use in asking questions here

Answer (score 7):

Remove it. I also do not understand why it is on Ask Ubuntu, when CyanogenMod is an Android rom, not Ubuntu. Yes, you might tell me about Ubuntu Touch, but Ubuntu Touch has its own tag (yes, look at askubuntu.com/tags)! CyanogenMod rom is a rom, not a Ubuntu flavour, nor version, it is only based on linux (not Ubuntu, that is a difference) kernel! So I say: **Remove!** People, you have it on Android Enthusiasts (and there it has 1633 questions and here 2)! But wait? If you remove that, look at *android* (and maybe *android-sdk*) tag too (*android-studio* might be good, if it is about fixing bugs in this program in Ubuntu)!

Answer (score 2):

I agree, remove it. Of the two questions tagged with it, neither has any problems directly relating to CyanogenMod. One is about Ubuntu Touch, and the error contains CyanogenMod in it, and the other one is about a hostapd hotspot where the device connected happens to be running Cyanogenmod.

Comment: With whom are you agreeing? You think the tag should be left alone? Or you think it should be removed?

Comment: Sorry, clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

I also agree with this.

Even though Ubuntu Touch was used to be based on CM, all the android is removed. So yeah, basicly this is NOT CM.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the tag, i have no idea **HOW** it was added, and had no relation to Ubuntu.
Linux is a kernel, cyanogenMod is just a rom... **REMOVE I SAY!**